# Add condition to show my posts to an existing query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This SQL statement shows the posts of everyone I follow.

How do I edit this so it also shows my posts along with the people I follow?

```
$query_posts = "
SELECT 
    post.sqlid, 
    post.status, 
    post.username_posting, 
    post.date_time, 
    post.status_id, 
FROM posts 
INNER JOIN followers 
    ON post.username_posting = followers.following 
WHERE followers.follower = '$login_user'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `OR`condition in your query with `post.username_posting`

```
$query_posts = "SELECT
   post.sqlid,
   post.status,
   post.username_posting, 
   post.date_time,
   post.status_id
FROM posts
INNER JOIN followers ON post.username_posting = followers.following
WHERE
followers.follower = '$login_user' OR post.username_posting = '$login_user'";
```